# disable time in INotes Calender Extlib

Tags: xpages

Im using the INotes Calendar from the Extension Library

the Calendar displays in every Entry the starttime.
is there a chance to disable it?

Comment: You mean the time shown near the subject in 2-week view, right?

Comment: Yes I would disable the time because i have only allday events

Comment: Did you find an answer here?